# Probing app's ability to receive push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to write some GUI elements that walk the user though accepting permissions. The AddressBook framework has:

```
ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
```

The ALAssetsLibrary framework has:

```
ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

etc...

However I can't find such a call for Push Notifications. In the UIApplication class, I only see how to register, unregister, and enabledRemoteNotificationTypes. The enabledRemoteNotificationTypes seems a little useful to see what has been enabled, but doesn't concretely say "user has denied this ability". The other classes have states of Unknown, Allowed, Denied, and Restricted.

In the AppDelegate, there are two methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```

That can be used to help determine access as well. Beside this, is there an API that I'm overlooking?